# Error: invalid BigNumberish value (argument="value", value={ "hex": "0xb3e3", "type": "BigNumber" }, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.7.1)

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, ethers.js, uniswap

I tried providing my own gas values converted to BigInts, Numbers, Strings, and JSBI's, changing the number values, ect

I also looked at some other answers but none resolved the error(s)

Expected Result: Transaction goes thru and approves money for spending by routerAddress

Error:

```
TypeError: invalid BigNumberish value (argument="value", value={ "hex": "0xb3e3", "type": "BigNumber" }, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.4.2)
        at makeError (file:///home/celestial/Documents/projects/auto-trading/web/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/utils/errors.js:113:21)
        at assert (file:///home/celestial/Documents/projects/auto-trading/web/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/utils/errors.js:136:15)
        at assertArgument (file:///home/celestial/Documents/projects/auto-trading/web/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/utils/errors.js:147:5)
        at getBigInt (file:///home/celestial/Documents/projects/auto-trading/web/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/utils/maths.js:90:5)
        at set gasLimit [as gasLimit] (file:///home/celestial/Documents/projects/auto-trading/web/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/transaction/transaction.js:327:44)
        at Transaction.from (file:///home/celestial/Documents/projects/auto-trading/web/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/transaction/transaction.js:667:29)
        at Wallet.sendTransaction (file:///home/celestial/Documents/projects/auto-trading/web/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/providers/abstract-signer.js:181:35)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
        at async send (file:///home/celestial/Documents/projects/auto-trading/web/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/contract/contract.js:199:20)
        at async Proxy.approve (file:///home/celestial/Documents/projects/auto-trading/web/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/contract/contract.js:232:16) {
      code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
      argument: 'value',
      value: [BigNumber]
```

Image of Error:[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doLKt.png)

Code for running approval function (erroring section)

```
// goerli chain
const wethAddress = '0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6';
const routerAddress = '0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45';

const provider = new JsonRpcProvider(PROVIDER_URL);
const approvalContract = new Contract(wethAddress, erc20Abi, provider);

console.log('approving');
await approvalContract.connect(wallet).approve(
    routerAddress,
    6500000000000000
);
console.log('approved');
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing basically says that ethersjs now send a `BigInt` not regular `Number` type.

You can get through this by simply parsing the Number your sending as `BigInt`

```js
    const approvalContract = new Contract(wethAddress, erc20Abi, provider);

    await approvalContract.connect(wallet).approve(
    routerAddress,
    BigInt("6500000000000000")
);
```

For **ethers.js v6** I would write it like so:

```js
    const approvalContract = new Contract(wethAddress, erc20Abi, provider);

    await approvalContract.connect(wallet)["approve(address, uint256)"](
    routerAddress,
    BigInt("6500000000000000"))
```

Be sure to check the data type of the function parameters in the contract use them as done here `["approve(address, uint256)"]`❤